# IIS 7.5 Compression In Web Config

Tags: iis, compression, iis-7.5, http-compression

What aspects of http compression can be specified in the web config.

I have gotten dynamic compression working via changes to the applicationHost file for iis, but I'd like to configure as much as possible inside the application's web config.

I have been unsuccesfull to do this outside of the applicationHost file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression for dynamic and static content can be enabled or disabled per website, but the technical parameters like the minimal file size (before a file is compressed), the location of the directory where compressed files are cached and the size of the compression cache per application pool can only configured on the server level (hence in applicationHost.config).

Comment: Is this verified?  I enabled everything in my app host, verified it was working, then I removed the mime type I was looking for, then tried setting this in the web config with no success.

Comment: That's what I said, you can only enable it or disable it, you can't change the parameters. So speaking config files, you can only override <urlCompression /> but not <httpCompression />. Even when I set <section name="httpCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" /> it still won't allow me to make any overrides or to add any mime types from web.config. Although I can't find any documentation from Microsoft that clearly states this. It's from my own experience and testing. PS: I had to restart IIS to let it pick up changes to applicationHost.config.